# How to execute Python test in virtual environment

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

[image: Error message]

I set up a virtual environment and installed `selenium`, `py.test` and `webdriverdownloader` furthermore I set up a system environment variable and added path to `geckodriver`

But when I executed Python test in command line it fails with error:

> geckodriver executable needs to be in path

What went wrong from my side?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium using Python - Geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your virtualenv, it's that Selenium requires an external driver to work. Geckodriver is for using with Firefox and you can download it from Mozilla's [GitHub](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases). Once you have downloaded it, just make sure that it is on your PATH. See [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10) if you don't know how to do that.

Comment: I downloaded Geckodriver and set it up in path. But this error is still there.

Comment: Did you restart your shell? Also, you can check if it worked by running `echo %path%` for command prompt or `echo $Env:Path` for PowerShell.